# WCF on a workgroup

Tags: wcf, certificate, nettcpbinding, workgroup

I have developed WCF windows service using net tcp binding. Its working fine when wcf client and wcf service both are in domain (in two different system)

Getting error when both system are in work group not in domain

please suggest what configuration i need to change .

Error :System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:58.9879193'. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Client Config

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint kind="discoveryEndpoint" address="net.tcp://localhost:8005/Probe" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RequestReplyNetTcpBinding">
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RequestReplyNetTcpBinding" contract="Test2ServLib.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="LargeEndpointBehavior">
        <identity>  
          <dns value="WCFServer" />  
        </identity>  
      <!--The behaviorConfiguration is required to enable WCF deserialization of large data sets -->
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="announcementBehavior">
          <!--The following behavior attribute is required to enable WCF serialization of large data sets -->
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceDiscovery>
            <announcementEndpoints>
              <endpoint kind="announcementEndpoint" address="net.tcp://localhost:8005/Announcement" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RequestReplyNetTcpBinding" />
            </announcementEndpoints>
          </serviceDiscovery>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1500" maxConcurrentSessions="1500" maxConcurrentInstances="1500" />
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="WCFClient"
                               storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                               storeName="TrustedPeople"
                               x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                        <serviceCertificate >  
                           <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>  
                        </serviceCertificate>  
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="LargeEndpointBehavior">
          <!--The behavior is required to enable WCF deserialization of large data sets -->
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="WCFClient"
                               storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                               storeName="TrustedPeople"
                               x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                        <serviceCertificate >  
                            <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
                        </serviceCertificate> 
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="disableEndpointDiscovery">
          <endpointDiscovery enabled="false" />
          <!--The behavior is required to enable WCF deserialization of large data sets -->
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="WCFClient"
                               storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                               storeName="TrustedPeople"
                               x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                        <serviceCertificate >  
                            <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
                        </serviceCertificate> 
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="LargeEndpointBehavior">
          <!--The behavior is required to enable WCF deserialization of large data sets -->
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            <clientCredentials>
              <clientCertificate findValue="WCFClient"
                                 storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                 storeName="TrustedPeople"
                                 x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                        <serviceCertificate >  
                            <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
                        </serviceCertificate> 
            </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="RequestReplyNetTcpBinding" receiveTimeout="05:00:00" openTimeout="00:00:59" closeTimeout="00:00:59" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="25000000" maxConnections="50" maxReceivedMessageSize="25000000" sendTimeout="00:05:00" listenBacklog="1500">
          <reliableSession ordered="false" inactivityTimeout="00:01:00" enabled="true" />
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Service Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="announcementBehavior">
      <!--The following behavior attribute is required to enable WCF serialization of large data sets -->
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      <serviceDiscovery>
        <announcementEndpoints>
          <endpoint kind="announcementEndpoint"
        address="net.tcp://localhost:8005/Announcement"
        binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="RequestReplyNetTcpBinding"/>
        </announcementEndpoints>
      </serviceDiscovery>
      <serviceThrottling
              maxConcurrentCalls="1500"
              maxConcurrentSessions="1500"
              maxConcurrentInstances="1500"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="WCFServer"
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            storeName="TrustedPeople"
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" revocationMode="NoCheck" mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount="false" />
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="disableEndpointDiscovery">
      <endpointDiscovery enabled="false"/>
      <!--The behavior is required to enable WCF deserialization of large data sets -->
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="WCFServer"
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            storeName="TrustedPeople"
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" revocationMode="NoCheck" mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount="false" />
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="LargeEndpointBehavior">
      <!--The behavior is required to enable WCF deserialization of large data sets -->
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="WCFServer"
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            storeName="TrustedPeople"
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" revocationMode="NoCheck" mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount="false" />
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
 </behavior>  
 </serviceBehaviors>  
 <service name="Test2ServLib.IService1"
   behaviorConfiguration="announcementBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8006/Service1"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="RequestReplyNetTcpBinding"
              contract="Test2ServLib.IService1"
              behaviorConfiguration="LargeEndpointBehavior" />
<bindings>  
            <netTcpBinding>  
                <binding RequestReplyNetTcpBinding>  
                    <security>  
                        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />  
                    </security>  
                </binding>  
            </netTcpBinding>  
        </bindings>  

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the information you provide, it is very likely that the error is caused by the large amount of transmitted data. NetTcpbing will have a higher transmission performance in the local area network. SO you have no errors in the same domain. The WCF default timeout period is 1 minute. If the data is not transmitted within a minute, an error will be reported. I suggest you extend the timeout period on the server side:

```
<bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding openTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 closeTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 receiveTimeout="00:20:00">
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Besides, please enable the windows feature for supporting NetTCP protocol.

[image]

[image]

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

**UPDATE**

If the client and server are not on the same machine, the client needs to provide windows credentials, because nettcpbinding defaults to windows authentication:

```
ServiceReference1.CalculatorClient calculatorClient = new ServiceReference1.CalculatorClient();
   calculatorClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "Administrator";
   calculatorClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "Password";
```

If this problem still exists, it is recommended to add a mex endpoint:

```
<endpoint address="mex"
binding="mexTcpBinding"
contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
```

**Set the Mode value to Message**:

```
<binding name="Binding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
```

In your configuration file, I found that you did not set the value of Mode.

This is my App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Microsoft.Samples.X509CertificateValidator.CalculatorService" behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
        <!-- use host/baseAddresses to configure base address provided by host -->
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8001/servicemodelsamples/service"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- use base address specified above, provide one endpoint -->
        <endpoint address="certificate" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding" contract="Microsoft.Samples.X509CertificateValidator.ICalculator"/>
         
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
        <!-- X509 certificate binding -->
        <binding name="Binding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
        
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            <serviceMetadata/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <!-- 
            The serviceCredentials behavior allows one to specify authentication constraints on client certificates.
            -->
            <clientCertificate>
             
                <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
            </clientCertificate>
            <!-- 
            The serviceCredentials behavior allows one to define a service certificate.
            A service certificate is used by a client to authenticate the service and provide message protection.
            This configuration references the "localhost" certificate installed during the setup instructions.
            -->
            <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    
  </system.serviceModel>

<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

Comment: The problem is still there

Comment: I have my bindings set to certificate authentication <netTcpBinding>  
                <binding RequestReplyNetTcpBinding>  
                    <security>  
                        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />  
                    </security>  
                </binding>  
            </netTcpBinding>